# else return statement is shadowing else if return statement

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, return

My first statement is working correctly but it shadows the else if statement below and just duplicates, maybe because the arguments are the same? I can't seem to figure out why since I am using semicolon and properly bracketing the conditions. I would love an explanation to the solution anyone comes up with!

```
function sayHiToGrandma(string) {
    if (string.toLowerCase() === 'hello') {
        return "I can't hear you!";
    }
    else if (string.toUpperCase() === 'HELLO') {
        return "YES INDEED!";
    }
}
```

Comment: `'Hello'.toLowerCase()` is `'hello'`. `'Hello'.toUpperCase()` is `'HELLO'`. Both will either be true or false at the same time.

Comment: The 2nd condition will never be reached if the string is any upper/lowercase combination of 'hello'

Comment: What do you mean that it "shadows" the else if statement? Do you mean that one call of the sayHiToGrandma function produces two return statements? If so that is impossible. Once you `return` from a function, by definition the function stops executing and the call stack moves on. So you will never see the else if body execute, the function will always return inside the first if body because their truth conditions are identical.

Comment: the way the lab is set up its very confusing. i dont think i really want to do the lab anymore im more or less just focused on finishing it as i dont want to leave it unfinish. idk if you guys are familiar with the learn.co page but its for this school the flatiron school. i just wanted to see what type of program they run. and @JF i had a feeling that was the case.

Comment: and @jcd, poor word choice on my part. i shouldve just said that it never reaches that part of thefunction, i see why tho

Answer (score 0):

In this case if your string is hello like  any combinations HEllo or any combination with small h,e,l,l,o and H,E,L,L,O in your if statement you are getting lowercase hello so it is satisfied in the if so it will execute the if and ignores all the remaining conditions
Thats why only I cant hear you will be returned but it wont go to the else if condition

try this :http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp
 if and else if with same condition only if will execute but not else if

Answer (score 0):

NVM I found it out. Instead of actually using a 'string' i used the string argument like this,

```
function sayHiToGrandma(string) {
  if (string === string.toLowerCase()) {
    return "I can't hear you!";
}
else if (string === string.toUpperCase()) {
    return "YES INDEED!";
} else if ('I love you, Grandma.') {
  return 'I love you, too.'
}
```

etc.etc.etc.etc
thanks for the comments fellas

Comment: `else if ('I love you, Grandma')` always succeeds. Did you mean to write `else if (string == 'I love you, Grandma.')`?